# Создание пользователя. Вход через SFTP. Ограничение доступа.

Tags: debian, linux

**Суть:** Создать пользователя, с доступом по SFTP, с невозможностью выхода выше своей корневой папки.

**Debian 6**

**Стоит LAMP**

Создаю пользователя:

```
useradd -d /home/test1/ -b /home/test1/data -g www-data -s /bin/bash test1passwd test1
```

В sshd_conf:

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftpMatch Group www-data        AllowTCPForwarding no        X11Forwarding no        ChrootDirectory %h/data        ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

В папку через **SFTP** входит. Выше нее не выходит. Но при этом я не могу ничего там создать или изменит, пишет **permission denied**.

Тогда я делаю так:

```
chown -R test1:www-data /home/test1/data
```

Теперь не заходит вобще.При попытке коннекта пишет:

> Ошибка:   Server unexpectedly closed network connection
>
> Ошибка:   Невозможно подключиться к серверу

Как сделать, что-бы пользователь мог войти и менять все в своей папке? Но не иметь возможности выхода из нее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

надо

```
chmod 0755 /home/test1/data/  /home/test1/chown root:root /home/test1/data/ /home/test1/
```

доступ на запись должен быть у директории ниже chroot, типа /home/test1/data/public-html

иначе

```
fatal: bad ownership or modes for chroot directory "/home/test1/data"
```

в /var/log/auth.log

обычно chroot делают просто в домашнюю директорию, но т.к. вы видимо не хотите чтобы пользователь имел доступ к собственным служебным файлам, вы делаете chroot в data, но менять файлы в data нельзя, потому-что его владелец root:root, поэтому надо сделать ещё один каталог в data  с владельцем test1:www-data и этот каталог и надо настраивать как домашний для веб сервера.

Comment: Я применил эти команды, редактировать/удалять и тд не могу всеравно

Comment: А все вроде разобрался.chown test1:www-data /home/test1/data

Comment: А как в папке пользователя сделать другого пользователя?Я если делаю как показывал выше, то Server unexpectedly closed network connection

Comment: зачем другого ? там прикол вот в чем, то куда вы делаете chroot, не может иметь владельца никого кроме root:root, дополню ответ.

Comment: Понятно) Спасибо большое.Я просто хотел сделать типа SFTP доступ так:Глобальный доступ к /home/main_user/data (юзер main_user)И второстепенный доступ тоже из SFTP к /home/main_user/data/second_user/ ( юзер second_user )Типо того...Тоесть был бы главный пользователь, который имел доступ ко всему в своей папке и мини пользователи, которые имели доступ к определенным папкам в папке основного пользователя.Это нужно что-бы несколько разработчиков ( С урезаными правами ) не могли получить полный доступ к коду всего проекта.Вот так вот

Comment: бессмысленно это пытаться делать, т.к. девелопер всегда может просто своим кодом запросить список каталогов, файлов и их содержимого. При усилении паранои, просто используйте git, с импортом в одну сторону, не давайте разработчикам запускать код на вашем сервере самим, а merge делать главным разработчиком.